# solve uncorrected sequence (4,3,2,1,5) and change it to corrected sequence depend on my suggestion

Tags: c++, arrays, sorting, sequence

I try to solve this problem and suggested that I do arrangement Ascending to make a correct sequence from small number Ascending to high one.

so i make this code by c++ :-

```
include<iostream.h>
int main()
  {
   int ar[5] = {4,3,2,1,5};
      int d;
        for (int i=0; i<=4; i++)
        cout<<ar[i]<<" ";
        cout<<endl;
       for (int x=0; x<=4; x++)
            {
          for(int y=x+1; y<=4; y++)
             if(ar[x] > ar[y])
           {
              d=ar[x];
           ar[x]=ar[y];
          ar[y]=d;

           for ( d=0; d<=4; d++)
            {
         cout<<ar[d]<<" ";
                 }
             return 0;
           }
         }
        }
```

i get this output

```
 Output
   4 3 2 1 5
   3 4 2 1 5
```

it's my first time with cplus
so what is the wrong with my conditions

Regards

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The algorithm is correct. You messed a bit with the braces.

```
#include <iostream>

using std::cout;
using std::cin;
using std::endl;

int main()
{
    int ar[5] = {4,3,2,1,5};
    int d;
    for (int i=0; i<=4; i++)
        cout<<ar[i]<<" ";
    cout<<endl;
    for (int x=0; x<=4; x++)
    {
        for(int y=x+1; y<=4; y++)
            if(ar[x] > ar[y])
            {
                d=ar[x];
                ar[x]=ar[y];
                ar[y]=d;
            }

    }
    for ( d=0; d<=4; d++)
    {
        cout<<ar[d]<<" ";
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Use tabulation properly so that it is easier to read and find such mistakes.

If your task has no limitations, remember about C++ built-in algorithms ([std::sort](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/sort) for example)